# Adding more than 1 route file to laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I can see this in `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
Route::prefix('api')
      ->middleware('api')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

  Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

But when I try to add one:

```
  Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('themes/myTheme/web.php'));
```

Then it doesn't pick up the second `web.php` file. But if I remove the first `web.php` reference, then the second one is picked up. So it seems Laravel only wants one `web.php`. However, even this doesn't work:

```
  Route::middleware('myTheme')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('themes/myTheme/web.php'));
```

Is there any way to get a second web.php file to work?

I've tried/considered:

- A workaround by including the web.php file from the main web.php file. But I'd prefer it if the route provider handled it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663132/how-to-add-multiple-route-file-using-routeserviceprovider-in-laravel) but it doesn't seem to work for Laravel 8:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/admin.php');
            require base_path('routes/category.php');
        });
}
```

Comment: I made a subfolder in my routes folder called test and a web.php file in it, for me this is working `routes/test/web.php`. Are you sure your file is located at  `themes/myTheme/web.php`. I also made a subfolder called test at `test/web.php` (so not in the routes folder) this is also working for me...

Comment: Yes, I know it's at the right place because it works if I remove the previous one. But the other route is not in /routes. It's actually in /storage/sites/mysite/routes/web.php. Would be odd if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple route file instead of one main route file in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182806/multiple-route-file-instead-of-one-main-route-file-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @OMiShah I think I might just go that route. Scuse the pun.

Comment: @coderama Hmm it probably has something to do with it, I mean I can only access items in my storage via requests. So your file might be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

In your `RouteServiceprovider.php` file modify the below part:

```
Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

and make it as:

```
Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
            require base_path('routes/test.php'); // replace the route file path
      });
```

and then make sure to clear the cached routes using the command:

`php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 1):

```
  Route::prefix('api')
      ->middleware('api')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

  Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

  Route::middleware('web')
      ->namespace($this->namespace)
      ->group(base_path('storage/routes/web2.php')); // 'themes/myTheme/web.php' in your case
```

This will work, but don't forget to run `php artisan route:cache` command after the change

Comment: Nope. Doesn't want to work. I'll fiddle a bit more. I'm obviously doing something wrong if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, so you don't have to keep updating your provider whenever you add a new file is to move your routes to a folder and loop inside it.

```
   Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
          ->group(function () {
                foreach (glob(base_path('routes/api/*.php')) as $fileName) {
                    require $fileName;
                }
            });
```